# I need to reformat my Vlookup formula in excel

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have a VBA code as you can see below, I recorded it. While recording it, it wrote the formula in offset format. So I don't know how to change the range

How can I convert;
`R3C[-3]:R[1488]C[2]` which is normally `B$3:G1489`

to:

B$3:(last active cell in column "G")

How can I do that?

```
Sub duzenle()

Columns("E:E").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("L1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("E12").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-3],C.A.!R3C[-3]:R[1488]C[2],4,0),IF(ISBLANK('2017'!RC[7]),"""",'2017'!RC[7]))"
Range("E12").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select
Columns("E:E").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("E1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False
Columns("L:L").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Range("A1").Select
MsgBox "'C.A' Degerleri Guncellenmistir."

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove some of your unnecessary `Select`, `Selection` and by replacing the first few code lines of yours:

```
Columns("E:E").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("L1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

With:

```
Columns("E:E").Copy Range("L1")
```

Regarding your formula, you need to replace `FormulaR1C1` with `Formula`, see code below:

```
With Worksheets("C.A.")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row '<--get last row with data in Column G from "C.A." sheet
End With

Range("E12").Formula = _
    "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B3,C.A.!B$3:G" & LastRow & ",4,0)...' <-- the rest of your formula
```

**Edit 1**: just corrected the Formula code line:

```
Range("E12").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B3,C.A.!B$3:G" & LastRow & ",4,0),IF(ISBLANK('2017'!L12)," & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ",'2017'!L12))"
```

Comment: @efe can tercan have you read my answer above ? any feedback ?

Comment: I just read that and tried but it gave an error on    'Range("E12").Formula = _"'  , I don't know why, see below 


'Sub duzenle()


Columns("E:E").Copy Range("L1")

    Range("E12").Select

    Application.CutCopyMode = False


With Worksheets("C.A.")

    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

End With


    Range("E12").Formula = _

        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B3,C.A.!B$3:G" & LastRow & 

",4,0),IF(ISBLANK('2017'!L12),"",'2017'!L12))"'

Comment: With the `_` character you can split a long command into several rows. It has to be the last character in the row. If you don't split the statement, remove the `_` character.

Comment: @efe can tercan  have you tried my edited code under **Edit 1** ? is it working for you as you intended ?